# Is it safe to use temporary tables when an application may try to create them for independent, but simultaneous processes?

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables

I am hoping that I can articulate this effectively, so here it goes:

I am creating a model which will be run on a platform by users, possibly simultaneously, but each model run is marked by a unique integer identifier. This model will execute a series of PostgreSQL queries and eventually write a result elswehere.

Now because of the required parallelization of model runs, I have to make sure that the processes will not collide, despite running in the same database. I am at a point now where I have to store a list of records, sorted by a score variable and then operate on them. This is the beginning of the query:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE row RECORD;
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ranked_clusters;
CREATE TEMP TABLE ranked_clusters AS (
    SELECT
        pl.cluster_id AS c_id,
        SUM(pl.total_area) AS cluster_score
    FROM
        emob.parking_lots AS pl
    WHERE
        pl.cluster_id IS NOT NULL
        AND
        run_id = 2005149
    GROUP BY
        pl.cluster_id
    ORDER BY
        cluster_score DESC
);

FOR row IN SELECT c_id FROM ranked_clusters LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Cluster %', row.c_id;
END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So I create a temporary table called `ranked_clusters` and then iterate through it, at the moment just logging the identifiers of each record.

I have been careful to only build this list from records which have a `run_id` value equal to a certain number, so data from the same source, but with a different number will be ignored.

What I am worried about however is that a simultaneous process will also create its own `ranked_clusters` temporary table, which will collide with the first one, invalidating the results.

So my question is essentially this: Are temporary tables only visible to the session which creates them (or to the cursor object from say, Python)? And is it therefore safe to use a temporary table in this way?

The main reason I ask is because I see that these so-called "temporary" tables seem to persist after I execute the query in PgAdmin III, and the query fails on the next execution because the table already exists. This troubles me because it seems as though the tables are actually globally accessible during their lifetime and would therefore introduce the possibility of a collision when a simultaneous run occurs.

<strike>Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for the explanation but I am not yet convinced that it is safe, because I have been able to execute the following code:</strike>

```
import psycopg2 as pg2

conn = pg2.connect(dbname=CONFIG["GEODB_NAME"],
                       user=CONFIG["GEODB_USER"],
                       password=CONFIG["GEODB_PASS"],
                       host=CONFIG["GEODB_HOST"],
                       port=CONFIG["GEODB_PORT"])
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor()

conn2 = pg2.connect(dbname=CONFIG["GEODB_NAME"],
                    user=CONFIG["GEODB_USER"],
                    password=CONFIG["GEODB_PASS"],
                    host=CONFIG["GEODB_HOST"],
                    port=CONFIG["GEODB_PORT"])
conn2.autocommit = True
cur2 = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable (tempcol INTEGER); INSERT INTO temptable VALUES (0);")
    cur2.execute("SELECT tempcol FROM temptable;")
    print(cur2.fetchall())
```

And I receive the value in `temptable` despite it being created as a temporary table in a completely different connection as the one which queries it afterwards. Am I missing something here? Because it seems like the temporary table is indeed accessible between connections.

The above had a typo, Both cursors were actually being spawned from `conn`, rather than one from `conn` and another from `conn2`. Individual connections in psycopg2 are not able to access each other's temporary tables, but cursors spawned from the same connection are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary tables are only visible to the session (=connection) that created them. Even if two sessions create the same table, they won't interfere with each other.

Temporary tables are removed automatically when the session is disconnected.

If you want to automatically remove them when your transaction ends, use the `ON COMMIT DROP` option when creating the table.

So the answer is: yes, this is safe.

---

Unrelated, but: you can't store rows "in a sorted way". Rows in a table have no implicit sort order. The only way you can get a guaranteed sort order is to use an `ORDER BY` when **selecting** the rows. The `order by` that is part of your CREATE TABLE AS statement is pretty much useless.

If you have to rely on the sort order of the rows, the only safe way to do that is in the SELECT statement:

```
FOR row IN SELECT c_id FROM ranked_clusters ORDER BY cluster_score 
LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Cluster %', row.c_id;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: +1. Just let me suggest using "ON COMMIT DROP" to avoid temp table retention when using a connection pool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I added a bit more to my question because it seems like I actually can access the temporary table with two different connections from Python

Comment: @1saac: of course you can if you created them in two different connections. The data **in** the tables will be specific to the session. You will see that if you insert different values in the two tables from both sessions

Comment: But in my example, the data I inserted only comes from the first connection, and yet the second connection is able to query that same data - shouldn't the temporary table only exist within the scope of the first connection?

Comment: @1saac I don't know Python, maybe it's not actually creating two connections. But I do know that data inserted in one session is **not** visible in other (phyiscal different) sessions. Try the same with two instances of `psql`

Comment: I'll take your word for it, I'll follow up with the psycopg2 library to dig a bit deeper into it. Thanks.

Comment: @1saac: you don't have to take my word it ;) you can verify this using `psql` (or any other SQL tool where you are certain that you have two different connections - which in turn can be verified by looking at `pg_stat_activity`)